# Android SDK - Preloading a small images gets my application to exceed memory

Tags: android, image, memory

I am trying to write a simple app for android. I am trying to preload 7 jpg images each of size ~75KB and resoluton 768x480. When run on HTC Flyer it runs fine. When run on HTC Evo 3D it crashes. Apparently I am allocating too much memeory:

```
1658880-byte external allocation too large for this process.
Out of memory: Heap Size=6663KB, Allocated=4297KB, Bitmap Size=25278KB, Limit=32768KB
Trim info: Footprint=6663KB, Allowed Footprint=6663KB, Trimmed=452KB
VM won't let us allocate 1658880 bytes
Clamp target GC heap from 33.136MB to 32.000MB
```

which seems quite weird. Am I supposed to create smaller images? I seems unlikely given today's high resolution screens. Am I suppose extend heap size? Well that's only supported from Android 3.0. What is the proper solution?
Btw. code I used for preloading images is:

```
    stringsImages = new Drawable[]{
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.strings0),
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.strings1),
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.strings2),
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.strings3),
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.strings4),
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.strings5),
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.strings6)
    };
```

To be sure to avoid possible confusion in calculations I am also using ~5MB additionally for calculations on audio data.

Comment: dare I ask why you are preloading the images? Why can't you load them when they are needed?

Comment: Wellcome these are images that are swapped quite often as they reflect audio property that's changing rapidly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running out of memory, try sub-sampling each drawable. This decreases the size of the image to save memory. See the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) to understand how that works. I've done this and saved memory and not ever really seen any quality difference. Try running this code on each image:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4; //the higher this number goes, the smaller the image gets
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.strings0, options);
```

Then you can set each bitmap to an `ImageView` with `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);`